# using XML deserialization in c#

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

how to deserialize the below xml :
Need to read AdapterName,ConnectorIndex and ViewType

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<MonitorConfiguration>
<System Type="1"> </System>
<Adapters>
<Adapter Name="P1" ></Adapter>
<Monitors>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P1" ViewType="C1"></Monitor>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P2" ViewType="C2"></Monitor>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P2" ViewType="C2"></Monitor>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P2" ViewType="C2"></Monitor>

</Monitors>
<Adapter Name="P2" ></Adapter>
<Monitors>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P4" ViewType="C3"></Monitor>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P5" ViewType="C5"></Monitor>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P6" ViewType="C6"></Monitor>
<Monitor ConnectorIndex="P7" ViewType="C7"></Monitor>
</Monitors>
</Adapters>
</MonitorConfiguration>
```

using Deserialize method

Comment: Did you try searching for the many possibilities that C# and .NET offer to read XML files?

Comment: You have downvotes because you've not shown any effort to do this yourself. People here will gladly help you if you have a problem with some existing code, but will (probably) not write code to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use serialization, first of all you should have a class with the same structure as your xml file.
So you'll have a class say `MonitorConfiguration` which have lists of `Adapters`, `Moniters` and so on...

You may find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part) post useful for basic understanding about xml serialization.

Once you have you xml equivalent type available, you can use `XmlSerializer` for creating object out of your xml.

```
    // De-Serializes the request into class object
    public T DeserializeXml<T>(XmlNode xmlToDesearialized)
    {
        if (xmlToDesearialized == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlToDesearialized");
        T deserializedObject = default(T);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlToDesearialized.OuterXml))
        {
            XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
            deserializedObject = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
        }
        return deserializedObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this -

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(new StreamReader(xml));

foreach (XmlNode x1 in xml.GetElementsByTagName("Adapter"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x1.Attributes["Name"].Name + "::" + x1.Attributes["Name"].Value);
}

var p = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Monitors");
foreach (XmlNode x in p)
{
    foreach (XmlElement e in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Attributes["ConnectorIndex"].Name + "::" + e.Attributes["ConnectorIndex"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Attributes["ViewType"].Name + "::" + e.Attributes["ViewType"].Value);
    }
}
```

But from next time on, try something before you ask a question.